# Header and footer by uploading PDF

Tags: pdf, header, footer

I have multiple PDFs for which I want to insert Header and footer to them automatically while taking printout. Please suggest how to proceed.

Header and footer should display in background and body of PDF should not get altered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for Windows:
You can use CIB pdf brewer, which is available at https://pdfbrewer.cib.de/. It is a free PDF processor.
Just select all PDFs, which should be processed in the file explorer and right click on CIB pdf brewer => convert. Then you can define a profile with a stationery paper (as pdf or png) which should contain your footer and header and all files will be processed according to that profile.

As a post-Action you could also define to print the resulting pdf to a printer directly.